# How to make ProGuard work in a simple way?

Tags: java, proguard

I tested ProGuard on a simple application. It works very well. However, when i tried to use it on something more complex, it thows all types of warnings and error like one class depends on other  or a  class tries to use reflection etc.

This is the configuration

```
-injars       Test.jar
-outjars      Test2.jar
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar    
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/jce.jar  
-printmapping myapplication.map 
-keep class com.teradata.** {*;}  
-keep class org.quartz.** {*;}   
-keep class org.terracotta.** {*;}  
-keep class com.sun.** {*;} 
-keep class javax.** {*;} 
-keep class org.apache.** {*;} 
-keep class org.slf4j.** {*;}   
-keep class com.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.test.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Is there any simple way to make it work. If something should be in `-keep`, can it automatically do so? Process as much as it can, and leave the rest .

I also  tried the gui version . But I couldn't figure out how to `-keep` the jars.

**Also it's too verbose even without the verbose keyword** . I can't get to the root of the problem because of enormous number of the duplicate error message like `Maybe blah blah` and then the same thing again and again .

**Is there any simple way to just make it work ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to be bothered by looking at the warnings and fix them appropriately (or use `-dontwarn` directives to ignore harmless ones), you can use the `-ignorewarnings` directive, which will instruct ProGuard to keep processing your application even if there are some warnings remaining.